# Do primitive variables have static-type and dynamic-type?

Tags: java, types

I learned that since Java is statically typed language, every variable has a static type and dynamic type.
However, the discussion of whether a variable is static or dynamic has virtually always been in the context of reference variables, and not primitive variables, so I'm hesitant about whether to I can use the terms 'static-type' and 'dynamic-type' when it comes to primitive variables ( perhaps because there's not much to it when trying to talk about static and dynamic types of primitives [ since they'll be the same ], but when one talks about reference variables the usage of these terms becomes fruitful because of Polymorphism ).

For example, if we have Class `A` that inherits from Class `B` and we write `B b = new A();`, then the static/compile-time type of `b` is `B`, but its dynamic/run-time type is `A`.

---

I was wondering, if we write for-example, `int num = 5;`, then is it ok to say that the static-type of `num` is `int` and the dynamic-type of `num` is `int` **?**

Also, can there be a case such that the static-type and dynamic-type of a primitive are different **?**  I tried to think of such an example by writing `int a = 5.5;`, but such definition of a variable won't compile unless I use casting on `5.5` ( auto-boxing does not occur in this case ).

I think that the static and dynamic types of a primitive will always be the same, but I can't justify it. Am I correct in this thinking? what is the justification for it **?**

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: static vs dynamic types conversation makes sense only when we're speaking about objects, since primitive types are not objects there is no such thing at all, there is only one type, of course you can say that static=dynamic for primitive types, but it is more like sophistry or casuistry at this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's be precise. The Java Language Specification [writes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-4.html):

> **Chapter 4. Types, Values, and Variables**
>
> The Java programming language is a statically typed language, which means that every variable and every expression has a type that is known at compile time.

and later:

> **4.12.1. Variables of Primitive Type**
>
> A variable of a primitive type always holds a primitive value of that exact primitive type.
>
> **4.12.2. Variables of Reference Type**
>
> A variable of a class type T can hold a null reference or a reference to an instance of class T or of any class that is a subclass of T.
>
> A variable of an interface type can hold a null reference or a reference to any instance of any class that implements the interface.

As you can see, a variable of primitive type can only hold values of that exact type, while a variable of reference type can hold values (references) to objects of that type, or any subtype thereof.

Therefore, a difference between the types of values and variables can only exist for reference types.

Note that the specification talks about the types of variables (which you call static type), and the type of objects (which you call dynamic type). It's nonsensical to say that a variable has a dynamic type, because a variable is a static thing.

Comment: But type of object is dynamic type, but dynamic type need not be an type of object, so we can also talk about dynamic type of a primitive. Although, since in the specification it says  "A variable of a primitive type always holds a primitive value of that exact primitive type." , this means that it won't be much sense to talk about static and dynamic type of a primitive since they will always be the same, but still the terms static-type and dynamic-type can apply for a primitive.